# Voltar para o fragment anterior ao clicar no botão voltar celular?

Tags: android, android-fragment, bottomnavigationview

Eu estou a tentar implementar a funcionalidade de voltar para trás e aparecer-me o `fragment` em que estive anteriormente.

Isto é: fragment1, fragment 2, fragment 3 e fragment 4.

Eu posso ir do fragment 1 para o 2, 3 e o 4 e assim sucessivamente, uma vez que, tenho uma `bottomNavigation`. O que acontece é que quando clico no botão de voltar para trás no telemóvel o aplicativo desliga e eu não consigo voltar ao fragment anterior...

Eu já vi inúmeros códigos, mas nenhum conseguiu me ajudar.

**Isto é parte da minha `MainActivity` da `BottomNavigation`:**

```
    BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    navigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_user);
}

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_user:
                    Navigation.findNavController(MainActivity.this, R.id.navHostFragment).navigate(R.id.user_dest);
                    activeFragment = new UserFragment();
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_maps:
                    Navigation.findNavController(MainActivity.this, R.id.navHostFragment).navigate(R.id.maps_dest, bundle);
                    activeFragment = new MapsFragment();
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_history:
                    Navigation.findNavController(MainActivity.this, R.id.navHostFragment).navigate(R.id.resume_dest);
                    activeFragment = new HistoryFragment();
                    return true;

            }
            return false;
        }
};
```

**Um código que vi (a maioria dos códigos utilizavam o `FragmentManager`):**

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(..............);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Não sei onde colocar estas partes de código e nem que parâmetros colocar no `fragmentTransaction.replace()`.

Alguma alma caridosa para me ajudar?

Comment: Tentei fazer aqui, mas não obtive sucesso, caso consiga por favor poste a resposta, é algo que já venho tentando a um bom tempo, o máximo que consigo é voltar o fragment pro primeiro fragment e depois no promixo botão voltar, fecha o app, irei fazer uma pergunta parecida no stack em inglês, se tiver resposta, posto aqui. Abç

Comment: Caso tenha interesse fiz esse exemplo: https://github.com/MurilloComino/BottomNavigationViewJetpack

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade o usuário deve usar o:

getFragmentManager().popBackStack()

Mais ou menos assim:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        Log.i("MainActivity", "popping backstack");
        fm.popBackStack();
    } else {
        Log.i("MainActivity", "nothing on backstack, calling super");
        super.onBackPressed();  
    }
}
```

Mais informações estão aqui:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack()

Comment: De fato! esqueci de comentar esse detalhe. Agora a resposta está completa!!!

Answer (score 0):

**Esse método faz ter o evento do botão voltar do celular:**

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Utilize-o para chamar o fragment anterior.

Comment: Utiliza-se o evento pra interceptar o click no botão voltar, correto, mas não é somente essa a dúvida do usuário.  Ele deseja que ao clique do botão o app navegue de volta pelos fragmentos anteriores, aqueles que estejam em backstack.

Comment: Essa resposta não está errada, mas falta um complemento aí... vou responder!